# Can you use Google Analytics with an intranet?

Tags: google-analytics, liferay, intranet

Can you use Google Analytics with an intranet?
I'm using [Liferay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liferay) as my intranet.

When setting up GA, you need to specify the Default URL starting with .
What would I specify in there if my intranet can be accessed by http://cs22web or by ip address?

Comment: Your question doesn't show a lot of research effort!

Comment: Yes you _can_ use Google Analytics with an Intranet. But _should_ you? No. http://analytics.angelfishstats.com/google-analytics-for-intranet/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick google of your question has led me to this page:

[How do I run Google Analytics on my intranet?](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55510)

**Quote:**

In order for Google Analytics to populate reports for your intranet usage, your corporate network needs to reach the ga.js JavaScript at

`http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js`

`http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif`

`https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js`

`https://ssl.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif`

If you can reach the above URL using your network's internet connection, you have satisfied the first requirement. Additionally, your intranet must be accessed using a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) such as http://intranet.example.com. The ga.js JavaScript will not work if your intranet is accessed using a non-FQDN (such as http://intranet).

I hope that helps!